# Symfony2: Google API v3, Namespace and Services. Why is it working?

Tags: php, symfony, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I wanted to use the Youtube Google API v3 in Symfony2.
**The following solution works perfectly fine. But I don't know exactly why =)**

**Question 1:**
How can Symfony2 be able to know what is `\Google_Client();` when I have not included any `use` statement or defined any service? How can Symfony guess the right path?
**Question 2:**
How can everything work when there are no namespaces in the google php api files? Aren't they mandatory in Symfony2? (Yes, I'm a newbie -.-' )
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php
**Question 3:**
I keep bumping in this word: "autoload". How is the autoload feature related to namespaces and composer?
**Question 4:**
If I wanted to define the Google Client (and maybe even the Youtube Service) as Syfmony2 Services, what path would I use for the `class` field? How should I define the Youtube service (arguments etc etc)?

```
google_client:
    class: path/to/client/class
```

---

Here is my **working code**. This is what I did:

A) Install the library with composer
`composer require google/apiclient`

B) Set up a youtubeAction() controller in my AcmeDemo Bundle

```
/**
 * @Route("/youtube", name="_youtube")
 * @Template()
 */
public function youtubeAction() {

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Youtube_Examples");
    $apiKey = "<my_API_key>"; // Change this line.
    // Warn if the API key isn't changed.
    if (strpos($apiKey, "<") !== false) {
        echo missingApiKeyWarning();
        exit;
    }
    $client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

    $service = new \Google_Service_YouTube($client);

   // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
   // query term.
    $searchResponse = $service->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
        'q' => 'geek and sundry',
        'maxResults' => 10,
    ));
    $videos = array();
    $channels = array();
    $playlists = array();
    // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists    of
    // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
        switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
            case 'youtube#video':
                $videos[]= array("title" => $searchResult['snippet']['title'], "video_id" => $searchResult['id']['videoId']);
                break;
            case 'youtube#channel':
                $channels[]= array("title" => $searchResult['snippet']['title'], "channel_id" => $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
                break;
            case 'youtube#playlist':
                $playlists[]= array("title" => $searchResult['snippet']['title'], "playlist_id" => $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
                break;
        }
    }

    return array(
        'youtube_videos' => $videos,
        'youtube_channels' => $channels,
        'youtube_playlists' => $playlists
    );

}
```

C) Display the fetched results in a Twig template `youtube.html.twig`

```
<!-- Page header, body, etc -->
<h3>Video List</h3>
<ul>
{% for video in youtube_videos %}
<li>{{ video.title }} ({{ video.video_id }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<h3>Channels list</h3>
<ul>
{% for channel in youtube_channels %}
<li>{{ channel.title }} ({{ channel.channel_id }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<h3>Playlists</h3>
<ul>
{% for playlist in youtube_playlists %}
<li>{{ playlist.title }} ({{ playlist.playlist_id }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<!-- Some other html code for the page -->
```

Comment: Autoload is the key: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php.  And composer creates one for you under vendor/autoload which is how symfony knows about Google classes.  The backslash in front of the class name is what makes non-namespaced classes work just fine. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thank you. This answers question 3, and a part of question 1.

Comment: So, every class that has no namespace declared (like Google API Client class) automatically goes in the global namespace, right? And prefixing a class name with a backslash, tells php that the class is to be fetched from the global namespace, right? What puts the google client class in the global namespace is composer (thanks to the autoload_classmap.php file) which probably tracks all non-namespaced classes (I presume).

Comment: Yep, yep and yep.  Pretty much covers all 4 of your questions.  For making a service, use the class name.  No need for a file path.

Comment: Best comment ever =) P.s. I don't know what is the best practice in this case, but if you write an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the right one.